# image.size is not giving proper dimensions of the image

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm unable to get the width and height of an image in given website.
I can get proper height and width if I use `total=im.size` but how to extract width and height separately.

Here is the code that is being used.

```
from selenium import webdriver
class Testawgp(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser=webdriver.Chrome()
        self.browser.get("http://www.awgp.org")

    def test_image_ratio(self):

        self.image=self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//img")
        for im in self.image:
            width, height= im.size
            print width, height

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()
```

Comment: size property is a dict

Comment: Corey Goldberg, how can we extract height and width parameter by this ? Because by using width, height= im.size doesnot see any error but output only print width and height text multiple time. Want to get separate parameter height and width for further process on images.

Comment: see my answer for explanation

Answer (score 0):

> width, height= im.size

This doesn't work because the `size` property of a `WebElement` is a dictionary... but you are trying to unpack it like a tuple.

To get the image dimensions, you must access the values for the corresponding `width` and `height` keys in the `size` dictionary.

For example, the following code will print dimensions of each image on the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.awgp.org')
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for img in images:
    dimensions = img.size
    width = dimensions['width']
    height = dimensions['height']
    print('{}x{}'.format(width, height))
```

Comment: Thanks Corey for the explanation. Now it works for me with  access the values width and height keys in the size dictionary.